# how to stop a td of table from scrolling among other tds of same table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

As my question suggests i am a beginner and i have one table who has 2 td in html and assume height of one td (.sidebar) is 1000px and height of another td(.content) is 5000px, now i want to scroll both td with the main body scroll which is the default behavior but what i want is

1. when main body is going scroll down :- then while first td(.sidebar) reached its bottom it should stop scrolling and another td(.content) should scroll down to his height which is 5000px
2. When main body is going scroll up :- then while body scroll reached to the height of the first td(.sidebar) then it should start scrolling with the main body scroll.

i have write the js code to identify when is scroll is going up and when it is going down but dont have luck to do this,i cannot fixed the position of td(.sidebar) because it will make out of flow of the parent element layout. please anybody could help me,any hint please [JS Fiddle here][1]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Document</title>
<script>
window.onscroll = function(){homeScroller()};

var lastScrollTop = 0;
var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
function homeScroller() {
    if(st> lastScrollTop){
        if(st == $('.sidebar').height()){
            //stop sidebar td from scrolling with main body scroll
        } 
    }else{
        if(st == $('.sidebar').height()){
            //start sidebar td from scrolling with main body scroll
        } 
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
}

</script>
<style>
   html {
       display: table;
       margin: auto;
       width:100%;
   }

 body {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align:center;
  }      
  .center-content{
      width:100%;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
}
.container{
}
.sidebar{
    vertical-align:top;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.content{
    vertical-align:top;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center-content" align="center"> 
        <table class="container" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=40>
        <tr><td class="sidebar" align="" height="1000px" style="">
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
        </td><td class="content" height="5000px" width="">  
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</br>
        </td></tr>
        </table>
</div>   

</body>
</html>

<script>
</script>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you are after.  There are a few ways to optimize this, but I think this should get you going.  The **-20** in **sbTop** is just to give a little visual padding to the sidebar bottom.

```js
for (var i=0; i<50; i++){
  if (i < 25) { $(".sidebar").append("row " + i + "<br />") };
  $(".content").append("row " + i + "<br />")
}

$(window).on("scroll", function(){
  var wScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var wHeight = $(window).height();
  var wScrollBottom = wScrollTop + wHeight;
  var sbHeight = $(".sidebar").height();
  var sbTop = Math.max(wScrollBottom - sbHeight - 20, 0);

  $(".sidebar").css("top", sbTop + "px");
});
```

```css
table { width: 80%; margin: auto; }

tr { vertical-align: top; }

.sidebarContainer {
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.content {
  background-color: mistyrose;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="sidebarContainer"><div class="sidebar"></div></td>
    <td class="contentContainer"><div class="content"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No need `.sidebarContainer {position:relative}` and `.sidebar {posistion:absolute}`. `onscroll` change `margin-top` property.

Comment: @user5851956, I'm not sure I am following what the problem is.  Perhaps if I set the table width to less and 100% you could try again and let me know what the problem is.

Comment: @JonSG i added some more description( html and body css and and center div as i found this is the best way to start a design if i have some header div also) to my question also added screenshots for position as absolute with 100% table width design. thanks

Comment: @AlexKudryashev - i am trying to implement your suggestion. thanks

Comment: @AlexKudryashev is it possible to implement it without making position as absolute or fixed whether on scroll or either way? how i could stop scroll of an element using margin-top property?

Comment: `$(".sidebar").css("margin-top", sbTop + "px");`

Answer (score 0):

I not sure if this will help, because I am not sure if I understood well, but I change a little bit your code, and instead of using table I am using div. so the code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <style>
        .container{
        }
        .sidebar{
          vertical-align:top;
          background-color: #fc0;
          width: 200px;
          height: 1000px;
          padding:20px;
          float:left;
        }
        .content{
          background-color: #0fc;
          padding:20px;
          vertical-align:top;
          height:5000px;
          position: inherit;
          display: block
          top:7px;
          left: 250px;
          float: left;
        }
        .fixed{
          position: fixed;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
        </div>
    <div id="content" class="content fixed">    
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
    window.onscroll = function(){homeScroller()};
    $('div#content').width($(window).width()-299);
    // var lastScrollTop = 0;
    function homeScroller() {
        var st = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop(); 
        // console.log('sidebar: ' + $('.sidebar').height() + ' | st: ' + st);
        console.log($(window).width()-299);
        // if(st > lastScrollTop){
            if(st >= $('.sidebar').height() && $('div#content').hasClass('fixed')){
                //stop sidebar td from scrolling with main body scroll
                $('div#content').removeClass('fixed');
            } 
        // }else{
            if(st < $('.sidebar').height() && !$('div#content').hasClass('fixed')){
            //  //start sidebar td from scrolling with main body scroll
                $('div#content').addClass('fixed');
            } 
        // }
    }
        // lastScrollTop = st;
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this can give you some help.
Have fun Programming!

Comment: thanks for answering, as i mentioned in question i cannot make position is fixed or display is block because it will make (div or td or any element) out of the flow of the parent layout. another problem in the solution you had given is it will not fit for different resolution as i have tried it before you have give this to me and there is not way of fix it for all the resolution even with media queries. and do you think it is correct design?